# What does より means in this context?

Tags: meaning

I am familiar with the use of より in making comparisons. However, the use of より in this following context certainly does not mean "than" and so I would gladly appreciate if someone can help me provide a clarification of why より is used in this case.

> 同僚や上司との関係を築くことは日本語の力より必要です。

Basically, this sentence is trying to say that having the ability to speak Japanese is essential in building relationship with co-workers.

Comment: `having the ability to speak Japanese is essential in building relationship with co-workers` would be more like 「同僚や上司との関係を築くには日本語の力が必要です。」

Answer (score 4):

This より *is* for making a comparison between 同僚や上司との関係を築くこと and 日本語の力.

> 同僚や上司との関係を築くことは日本語の力より必要です。
>   Building relationships with your colleagues and superiors is more necessary than your Japanese skill.

Comment: What is the difference between using は、より and 方が、より? Just politeness?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira It doesn't affect English translation, but conceptually Xは／が～より～ is a sentence explaining X's quality, while ～の方が～より～ describes the comparison itself.